# Azure Websites Kudu REST API - Authentication in Python

Tags: python, azure, api, python-requests

I am trying to access the Azure Kudu Web API interface to get historical information about my WebJobs.  The URL is https://myfakewebappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/HubSpot/history

This works just fine in a browser with a one time (first time you login) user and password authentication.

When I call it with a python script using the requests library, I get a 401 response code and 'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="site"'.  I then send another request:

resp = requests.get('https://myfakewebappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/HubSpot/history', auth=('actualuser', 'actualpassword')).  I use the user and Password that work using my browser.

I get the same 401 response code again with the same response.headers.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Worked like a charm!!  Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

The Authentication of the [WebJobs Kudu API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API) is via basic auth, to call the API successfully in python, please follow the steps below.

1.Navigate to the Azure portal -> your web app which has the webjob -> click `Get publish profile`.

[image]

2.Open the downloaded file with the format `joyweb11.PublishSettings` in step 1, note down the `userName` and `userPWD` in this file.

3.Then use the code below, replace the value of `username` and `password` with the values in step 2, also replace the webapp name in the `url` with yours, it works fine on my side.

```
import requests
from base64 import b64encode

username = '$joyweb11'
password = '7pWclexxxxxJlHwoLRwtrneE'
base64AuthInfo = b64encode((username+':'+password).encode('ascii')).decode('ascii')

url = 'https://joyweb11.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/HubSpot/history'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64AuthInfo}

response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm!!

Comment: Thanks!. I spent about 2 hours trying to authenticate using my Microsoft username and password, and didn't understand why I was keep getting 401 Unauthorized.